# Return all possible values A and B could correspond to - Python

Tags: python-3.x, math, linear-algebra

I am looking for a program that will find all the possible values of A and B, suppose they could be anywhere from -Infinity to +Infinity. Is there any way I could find all the possible values that A and B could be? Eg, I mean if A and B could be anywhere from 1 to 3:

```
A = 1, B = 1;
A = 2, B = 2;
A = 3, B = 3;
A = 1, B = 2;
A = 1, B = 3;
A = 2, B = 1;
A = 2, B = 3;
A = 3, B = 1;
A = 3, B = 2;
```

Can I do this in python, just with A and B having no limit other than being whole numbers?
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: There is literally no way to generate such a list of numbers, since you're asking to go from -infinity to +inifinty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from itertools import permutations
low, high = 1, 3 # whatever numbers you want
all_possible_pairs = permutations([i for i in range(low, high, 1)], 2)
```

You can check out the itertools module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

If you're asking for *all* pairs from -inf to positive inf, then no, this is mathematically impossible - there is literally an infinite number of pairs.